# Regex returning uncaptured group instead of captured

Tags: javascript, regex

I've run into a strange problem that I can't seem to get around...
Basically, I've got this Regex that's returning the stuff that I don't have in a capture group, and it's not returning the actual captured group.  Here is the Regex:

```
"localhost/a/b/c".match(/\/a\/b\/(.*?)/g);
```

To my knowledge, this is supposed to return `["c"]`...  But it returns:

```
["/a/b/"]
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought captured groups were supposed to be returned, not ignored.

Comment: The problem here is the `/g` modifier and a missing `$` anchor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:  "localhost/a/b/c".match(//a/b/(.+)/)[1]

In your original regex `"localhost/a/b/c".match(/\/a\/b\/(.*?)/g);`

- the `.` means any character
- the `*` means previous character class matched  0 - infinite times
- the `?` means to match as few of previously specified characters as possible while still matching the rest of the regex but since there is nothing after the group this group will effectively capture nothing
- you dont seem to need the `g` modifier here at least not with this example.
- access your matched group by its position in the returned array where [0] is the full match, [1] is the first capturing group, etc...

```js
$('#myDiv').append( "localhost/a/b/c".match(/\/a\/b\/(.+)/)[1] );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"><div>
```

Comment: Thanks, why does `(.+)` work, while `(.*?)` doesnt? They're both capture groups, right?

Comment: because `+` means a matching character matched 1 or more times while `*`  means a matching character matched 0 or more times. But more to the point `*` with `?` right behind it and no more matching requirements after the group will cause your capture group to capture no characters at all. See my edit above

Comment: You can also use `(.*?)$`, using the `$` to match end of string. He's right, though; `.*` will match any character _`0 or more`_ times while `.+` will match it _`1 or more`_ times.

Comment: @Makaze, thanks.  It seems there is still a bit I need to learn about Regex.

Comment: for what it's worth regexbuddy (http://www.regexbuddy.com/) helped me quite a lot. It's great to be able to see what the regex is doing live as you make it. Its like $20 or so but well worth it IMHO